# Way to quit the most outer function from an inner function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have code that looks like this:

```
def lab():
    letter = prompt() 
    def experiment_1():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check")
            #Would there be a way to quit the lab function right here?
    def experiment_2():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check2")

    experiment_1()
    experiment_2()
lab()
```

Would there be a way for me to quit the lab function right after I print "check"? I tried putting return at the end of `experiment_1` but that just seems to go right to the next function which is `experiment_2`.

Comment: where are you calling the nested functions? As is, you're just defining two nested functions.

Comment: This looks like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for exceptions, there's not really enough context to tell.

Comment: Return a boolean from the inner function and in the outer function check whether the function wants to exit or continue.

Comment: Why not just have if statements? What's the purpose of the convoluted inner function implementation that doesn't actually enable the flow of control you want?

Comment: This is one of those classic examples of a simple issue without a simple fix. Why there isn't a simple solution like calling something along the lines of `return all` or `return outer` in python is just frustrating, to say the least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most obvious way is to raise an exception. It will allow you to get out from any depth. Define a custom exception and catch it at some outer level. For example:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass

def _lab():
    letter = prompt() 

    def experiment_1():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check")
            raise MyError

    def experiment_2():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check2")

    experiment_1()
    experiment_2()

def lab():
    try:
        return _lab()
    except MyError:
        return

lab()
```

This particular example is kind of ugly, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments section, you can pass a flag to the outer function

```
def lab():
    letter = prompt()

    def experiment_1():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check")
            return True
        return False

    def experiment_2():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check2")

    if experiment_1():
        return

    experiment_2()

lab()
```

But you should improve your question because it sounds like you are trying to solve *another* problem. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score -2):

You can put `return` statement just in the place that you want to function ends. In you can returns any other thin would be  `return var1 var2`

```
def lab():
    letter = prompt() 
    def experiment_1():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check")
            # Would there be a way to quit the lab function right here?
            # you have to put return just here
            return
    def experiment_2():
        if letter == 1:
            print("check2")

    experiment_1()
    experiment_2()
lab()
```