# End a running function using inner function with tkinter input GUI form, and display a warning message when exiting the GUI in between

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the `f2` to end not itself, but rather completely the parent function `f1` while being executed, with a command. I know that `return` is used to end a function, but it doesn't work here at a sub-level.

So my question is what are these commands (or sets of lines) and how can I implement them in my code? Example snippet here:

```
def f1:
    do something
    def f2:
        do something
        # need a command here
    f2()
    do something

f1()
```

It is noteworthy that the code shall be running a `while True:` loop at the time of discontinuing function.
I used tkinter library button to execute a sub function **(which means that the sub-function cannot return a value to a variable)**, but am unable to end the main function from within that set of code.

here is the tkinter code:

```
tk.Button(root, text='Click me', command=f2)
```

Here `command = f2` executes f2() when tk.Button is pressed, but the value is not returned anywhere. Probably a local or global variable flag can be used inside f2...

*[Way to quit the most outer function from an inner function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199948/way-to-quit-the-most-outer-function-from-an-inner-function)  --  This doesn't solve my problem since I must not define a class or error in my code.
Is there another method to do so?*

EDIT:
I think I am unable to convey the problem I am facing properly.

At this point it is just a mess

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
from PIL import ImageTk
lst = []
cnt = 0


black = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (50, 50, 50)
white = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (240, 240, 240)
red = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (255, 80, 80)
yellow = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (255, 220, 80)
green = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (120, 255, 150)
blue = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0, 220, 240)
purple = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (120, 80, 255)

window_icon = 'icon.jpg'


######## Non-iterables ########

def set_root():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()  # create only one instance for Tk()
    root.withdraw()


def root_attributes():
    root.iconphoto(True, ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=window_icon))
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)


#################################


def root_win():
    global cnt
    cnt += 1

    set_root()

    if cnt == 1:
        root_attributes()
        
    global lst
    root.deiconify()

    w_root = 500
    h_root = 320

    pos_right = round(root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - w_root / 2)
    pos_down = round(root.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - h_root / 2)

    root.title('Enter the values')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(w_root, h_root, pos_right, pos_down))
    root.configure(bg=white)

    tk.Label(root, text='Enter the values', font=('bold', 30), bg=white, fg=black).place(x=70, y=20)
    tk.Label(root, text='Enter width here:', font=('bold', 15), bg=white, fg=black).place(x=50, y=100)
    tk.Label(root, text='Enter height here:', font=('bold', 15), bg=white, fg=black).place(x=50, y=140)

    val1 = tk.Entry(root, bd=0, font=('bold', 15))
    val1.place(x=280, y=102, width=170)

    val2 = tk.Entry(root, bd=0, font=('bold', 15))
    val2.place(x=280, y=142, width=170)

    lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Min: 5, Max: 100', font=('bold', 15), bg=white, fg=purple)
    lbl.place(x=170, y=260)

    def enter():
        global lst
        if val1.get() == '' and val2.get() == '':
            lbl.config(text='Please enter width and height!')
            lbl.place(x=80, y=260)

        elif val1.get() == '':
            lbl.config(text='Please enter a width!')
            lbl.place(x=145, y=260)

        elif val2.get() == '':
            lbl.config(text='Please enter a height!')
            lbl.place(x=140, y=260)

        else:
            wid, hit = 0, 0
            try:
                wid = round(float(val1.get()))
                hit = round(float(val2.get()))
            except:
                lbl.config(text='Please enter value from 5 to 100!')
                lbl.place(x=70, y=260)

            if not 5 <= wid <= 100 or not 5 <= hit <= 100:
                lbl.config(text='Please enter value from 5 to 100!')
                lbl.place(x=70, y=260)

            else:
                lbl.config(text='INPUT ACCEPTED !!!!')
                lbl.place(x=130, y=260)
                lst = [wid, hit]
                root.deiconify()

    def clr():
        val1.delete(0, 'end')
        val2.delete(0, 'end')
        lbl.config(text='Min: 5, Max: 100')
        lbl.place(x=170, y=260)

    enter = tk.Button(root, text='Enter', font=('bold', 15), bd=0, fg=black, bg=green, activebackground=blue,
                      command=enter)
    enter.place(x=300, y=200)
    enter.configure(width=8)

    clear = tk.Button(root, text='Clear', font=('bold', 15), bd=0, fg=black, bg=red, activebackground=yellow,
                      command=clr)
    clear.place(x=100, y=200)
    clear.configure(width=8)

    root.mainloop()

# set_root()

root_win()

if not lst:
    action = msgbox.askyesno(title='Exit prompt', message='Are you sure you want to exit?\nYes: Exit\nNo: Restart\n',
                             icon='warning', default='no')
    if not action:  # Returns True or False
        root_win()
    else:
        quit()

print(lst)
```

I expect the code to form a GUI for input of 2 values, and if the values do not meet requirements, it should continue GUI interface untill requirements are met. Also, if user closes the GUI in between, there should be a confirm dialogue box to exit or restart "global function". Thing is, `root.destroy()`  help exit global function but some lines are not iterable, like iconphoto. It gives an error.

Comment: What's stopping you from defining a class?

Comment: Does `while` work well with your GUI ? Can you show more parts of code than just "_do something here_". What is stopping the function from ending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind folks, I found the solution I needed:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
from PIL import ImageTk

lst = []


black = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (50, 50, 50)
white = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (240, 240, 240)
red = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (255, 80, 80)
yellow = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (255, 220, 80)
green = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (120, 255, 150)
blue = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0, 220, 240)
purple = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (120, 80, 255)

window_icon = 'icon.jpg'


def root_win():
    global lst

    root = tk.Tk()  # create only one instance for Tk()

    w_root = 500
    h_root = 320

    pos_right = round(root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - w_root / 2)
    pos_down = round(root.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - h_root / 2)

    root.iconphoto(True, ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=window_icon))
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.title('Enter the values')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(w_root, h_root, pos_right, pos_down))
    root.configure(bg=white)

    tk.Label(root, text='Enter the values', font=('bold', 30), bg=white, fg=black).place(x=70, y=20)
    tk.Label(root, text='Enter width here:', font=('bold', 15), bg=white, fg=black).place(x=50, y=100)
    tk.Label(root, text='Enter height here:', font=('bold', 15), bg=white, fg=black).place(x=50, y=140)

    val1 = tk.Entry(root, bd=0, font=('bold', 15))
    val1.place(x=280, y=102, width=170)

    val2 = tk.Entry(root, bd=0, font=('bold', 15))
    val2.place(x=280, y=142, width=170)

    lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Min: 5, Max: 100', font=('bold', 15), bg=white, fg=purple)
    lbl.place(x=170, y=260)

    def enter():
        global lst
        if val1.get() == '' and val2.get() == '':
            lbl.config(text='Please enter width and height!')
            lbl.place(x=80, y=260)

        elif val1.get() == '':
            lbl.config(text='Please enter a width!')
            lbl.place(x=145, y=260)

        elif val2.get() == '':
            lbl.config(text='Please enter a height!')
            lbl.place(x=140, y=260)

        else:
            wid, hit = 0, 0
            try:
                wid = round(float(val1.get()))
                hit = round(float(val2.get()))
            except:
                pass

            if not 5 <= wid <= 100 or not 5 <= hit <= 100:
                lbl.config(text='Please enter value from 5 to 100!')
                lbl.place(x=70, y=260)

            else:
                # lbl.config(text='INPUT ACCEPTED !!!!')
                # lbl.place(x=130, y=260)
                lst = [wid, hit]
                root.destroy()

    def clr():
        val1.delete(0, 'end')
        val2.delete(0, 'end')
        lbl.config(text='Min: 5, Max: 100')
        lbl.place(x=170, y=260)

    def closing():
        if msgbox.askyesno(title='Exit prompt', message='Are you sure you want to exit?',
                           icon='warning', default='no'):
            root.destroy()
            print('Have a nice day!')
            quit()

    ext = tk.Button(root, text='Cancel', font=('bold', 15), bd=0, fg=black, bg=red, activebackground=yellow,
                    command=closing)
    ext.place(x=60, y=200)
    ext.configure(width=7)

    clear = tk.Button(root, text='Clear', font=('bold', 15), bd=0, fg=black, bg=yellow, activebackground=red,
                      command=clr)
    clear.place(x=200, y=200)
    clear.configure(width=7)

    enter = tk.Button(root, text='Enter', font=('bold', 15), bd=0, fg=black, bg=green, activebackground=blue,
                      command=enter)
    enter.place(x=340, y=200)
    enter.configure(width=7)

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closing)
    root.mainloop()


root_win()
print(lst)
```

The key was this line set:

```
    def closing():
        if msgbox.askyesno(title='Exit prompt', message='Are you sure you want to exit?',
                           icon='warning', default='no'):
            root.destroy()
            print('Have a nice day!')
            quit()
```

Comment: Nice! Since this is the solution to your problem, be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @defarm He'd have to wait 48 hours, but that would definitely be the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

One way can be to raise an exception from `f2`, then catch that exception in `f1` and then return early:

```py
def f1():
    # do something
    def f2():
        print('Hello')
        # need a command here
        raise StopIteration()
        print('World!')

    try:
        f2()
    except StopIteration:
        return

    print('World')
    # do something

f1()
```

Outputs:

```
Hello
```

I'm not exactly sure where you're defining the `while` loop mentioned. If it's outside of `f1` entirely, I'd delegate handling of the error within such a loop itself - or you could even wrap the `while` loop with a try-except if absolutely needed. If you go with latter approach, I'd suggest creating a custom exception class and then catching that specific error; this way you can be sure you're handling only the error that you've raised from within `f2` for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways I would tackle this - and it depends on the complexity of the problem.

Simple calculations can be achieved like so:

```
def foo(*args,**kwargs):
    bar = lambda ... : ...
    do something
    final = bar(x)
    return final   

foo()
```

If the function has added complexity, it makes sense to use a class (or classes depending on the complexity) like so:

```
class thing_youre_classifying(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __any_other_boilerplate_methods_needed__(self):
        ...

    def foo(self):
        do something

    def bar(self):
        do something
        x = f1()

thing = thing_youre_classifying()
thing.bar()
```

This is mostly for readability (and probably other important things).

Or, if `foo` and `bar` are wildly different (say in `foo` you're parsing a database and `bar` you're doing statistical analysis), you'll want to check out class inheritance.

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        initialize each instance of foo with args and kwargs

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        foo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

instance = bar()
instance.foo()
```

I want to point out that I did not include `*args` or `**kwargs` in `bar`'s boilerplate init function. That could also underline the difference between `foo` and `bar`.

The last thing that comes to mind is using decorators.

> "One of the main uses of decorators is that they allow us to add
> functionality to existing functions, without modifying the original
> function. This capability extends to class methods as well."
> -anonymous professor

```
def foo():
    def modifier():
        return foo.method_you_want()
    return modifier

@foo
def bar():
    do something
```

My gut tells me decorators are going to be the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: It seems I am novice at python, idk what's `foo` or `bar` or `@` or `modifier`, and what are they used for.
Or `*args` or even `*kwargs`

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are industry standards - throwaway names for general conversation. `@` and `modifier` relate to [decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/). `*args` and `**kwargs` (there are to asterices) are for [dynamically](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/) passing arguments. As far as being a novice goes... I'm a novice at `tkinter`! Keep asking questions!